# Branched from feature branch instead of develop

Tags: git, git-branch

I was doing a hotfix, and when I created the branch I forgot to switch back from an experminetal branch to develop before doing so.

```
   experiment -> hotfix
   develop
```

when it should be

```
   experiment
   develop -> hotfix
```

How do I move the branch to be an addition to develop and remove it from the experiment branch? I've seen a few questions like this but they seem to assume that you still want to include what in my case is the experiment. I still need to maintain the integrity of experiment though.

Comment: Have you committed or pushed?

Comment: What do you mean by "remove it from the experiment branch"? If you made the commit(s) on your hotfix branch your experiment branch is unaffected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If doing a non fast-forward update of the hotfix branch isn't a problem (the usual caveats apply if you want to do that), you can simply rewrite the hotfix branch to apply its changes to the tip of the develop branch instead:

```
git checkout hotfix
git rebase --onto develop experiment
```

This means: Find all commits reachable from hotfix but not from experiment (i.e. the commits unique to your hotfix branch) and move them onto the develop branch. Differently put, the base of the sequence of commits to move is defined as the experiment branch. The `--onto` argument specifies the new base of the sequence of commits, i.e. the new parent commit of the first commit being rebased.

If it's unacceptable to rewrite the history of the published branch, just start a new branch based on develop and copy your commits there.

```
git checkout -b hotfix2 develop
git cherry-pick experiment..hotfix
```

Comment: Great explanation! The only thing I'm still hazy on is the arguments for `--onto` I'm reading the docs on rebasing and not sure exactly what those arguments do

Comment: @Damon: Expanded one of the middle paragraphs to hopefully make it clearer.